# Can I use multiple distributions of ROS on same system?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a beginner in using ROS.

I installed lunar version of ROS using the following command

> sudo apt-get install
> ros-lunar-desktop-full

My doubt is can I do the following?

> sudo apt-get install
> ros-kinetic-desktop-full

> sudo apt-get
> install ros-indigo-desktop-full

Is it safe to install multiple distributions?

Any extra precautions to take?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280049/can-i-use-multiple-distributions-of-ros-on-same-system?/) by [hagm](https://answers.ros.org/users/33308/hagm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2018-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer: yes, *as long as the packages for that ROS version have been released for your OS*.

See [REP-3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html) for which ROS versions have been released for which OS.

> My doubt is can I do the following?

> ```
> sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full
> ```

> ```
> sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
> ```

No, because as you can see in `REP-3`, there is no overlap in the OS supported by Indigo and Kinetic.

You could install Kinetic next to Lunar, as they both support Ubuntu Xenial.

> Is it safe to install multiple distributions?

I'm not sure what the question is: what do you define as 'safe'? No packages from one ROS distribution should overwrite any files from others (that is enforced by `apt`), if that is what you are worried about.

> Any extra precautions to take?

Don't try to `source` the `setup.bash` of both and expect to be able to mix-and-match packages. As long as you keep things separated, you should be fine.

---

Edit: I should've closed this question, as there are way too many duplicates of it already:

- #q187548: *Can I install multiple ROS version on the same machine?*
- #q189567: *two ROS versions in the same time*
- #q103116: *Working with two ROS Versions on single system*
- #q10660: *What happened if I install two version of ROS?*
- #q76279: *Different ROS versions on multiple machines*
- #q58221: *How I manage multiple ros distributions*
- #q243347: *Can I install dual ROS version on the same machine?*

and so on.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-17**:
Note that if you really want / need to, a source install of Indigo on Ubuntu Xenial *might* be possible. It's probably going to be some work though (if at all possible).